# No validator could be found for constraint 'javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank' validating type 'java.lang.String'

Tags: java, hibernate, validation, hibernate-validator, javax.validation

I'm using Hibernate validator to validate my beans.

Actually I have this dependencies on my POM

```xml
    <!-- Hibernate validator - Bean validation API Implementation -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.11.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Verify validation annotations usage at compile time -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator-annotation-processor</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.11.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Unified Expression Language - Spec -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1-b06</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Unified Expression Language - Implementation -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.el</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

And this a pice of my bean

```
import org.hibernate.annotations.ColumnDefault;
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import java.util.Date;

public class Casa {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name="nomcaac") @NotBlank(message = "{casa.nomcaac.null}") @Size(min = 0, max = 300, message = "{casa.nomcaac.size}")
    private String nomcaac;
```

Now the problem comes when i try to validate my bean, i get this error message

> No validator could be found for constraint
>   'javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank' validating type
>   'java.lang.String'. Check configuration for 'nomcaac'

I can't figure out whats my problem, I think I have the right dependencies according to this [page](https://howtodoinjava.com/hibernate/hibernate-validator-java-bean-validation/).

Comment: Take a look at [their website](http://hibernate.org/validator/releases/6.0/). The `groupId` for Hibernate Validator is `org.hibernate.validator`, not `org.hibernate`.

Comment: It's not a big issue as we have a relocation anyway.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`@NotBlank` is new in Bean Validation 2.0 so I suspect you have an old Hibernate Validator version (e.g. 5.x) in your classpath somehow.

You should check your dependency tree with `mvn dependency:tree` (and your webapp looking for an old jar).

By the way, your javax.el dependencies are incorrect: please refer to https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-validator/#using-hibernate-validator for the correct one.

Comment: Thanks, I have the same issue, just update Hibernate Validator version 6.x fixed